# How to handle NA value in a ggvis chart?

Tags: r, dplyr, ggvis

The following code gives a chart with a single column for the count of `a`. How do I tell ggvis to consider `NA` as a group as well?
I guess a little hack could be turning `NA` into a character but I was wondering if there is any more formal way to do that.

```
data_frame(group=c("a","a",NA)) %>% 
group_by(group) %>% dplyr::summarise(count=n()) %>% 
ggvis(x=~group,y=~count) %>% layer_bars()
```

Comment: `ggvis` does not currently have consistent `NA` handling: https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/247

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the handy function `addNA` to add an explicit NA-level to factors. This should work as a workaround. Also, `ggvis` seems to even have problem with the Text label "NA", so you must force it to show that label using `scale_nominal("x", domain = c("a", NA))`, or rename the label (f.ex. to "<NA>", but that renders as "`&lt;NA&gt;`" on my RStudio, so it's not a good solution)

```
data_frame(group=c("a","a",NA)) %>% 
  mutate(group = addNA(group)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% dplyr::summarise(count=n()) %>% 
  ggvis(x=~group,y=~count) %>% 
  layer_bars() %>%
  scale_nominal("x", domain = c("a", NA))
```

Comment: Didn't work for me until I added `scale_nominal("x", domain = c("a", NA))` at the end.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks for the fix! I assumed ggvis having problems with the actual NAs. Turns out it also has problems with "NA" as a factor level.